# asp.net mvc & Oracle Issue (Skip And Take)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g

I Use asp.net mvc and oracle database

I am using the expression below

```
var displayedCompanies = filteredCompanies
.Skip(10)
.Take(5);
```

but for some reason the Take and Skip do not work, that is ...
he always puts the complete SQL statement
"SELECT * FROM COMPANY"

Does anyone know if the SKIP AND TAKE not work in oracle?
what other choice do I have?

Answer (score 0):

That's right..
I'm using Linq To Entities (Everything is working)
Thank you